# Are there any special security problems which can affect open-source web applications?

Tags: open-source, security

I'd like to develop an open source web application.  Are there special security concerns which are introduced by the source code being open, in addition to the usual ones which apply to closed-source web applications?

Comment: this is a really broad topic, and not really adapted to stackoverflow, I'm afraid... To answer shortly, if the code is open, many eyes can see it, well-intentioned people as well as ill-intentioned ones. So, more vulnerabilities can be discovered and exploited, but they can also be fixed faster. It encourages developers to adopt a more sensible security model than "security through obscurity". This tends to lead to more overall security, in the end.

Comment: Thanks SirDarius.  That makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, no.

OK, I'll expand on that ;)

The only difference between open source and closed source is the fact that its easier for everyone to see the source code for open source app. Note that I said *easier*. There are plenty of examples of closed source code being 'stolen' or leaked.

When you implement an application you should assume that any attackers have access to the source code - that way you hopefully wont rely on 'security through obscurity' (a bad thing).